# Metrics from spring batch are not pushed to prometheus push gateway

Tags: spring-batch, prometheus, metrics, micrometer, prometheus-pushgateway

I followed the approaches mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66678874/7275579). Basically I have my local prometheus and push gateway setup using docker from [spring batch examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/metrics).

I have the below dependencies added in my `build.gradle` which means `PrometheusPushGatewayManager` bean is auto-configured and needs to push metrics to the gateway configured.

```
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.8.4")
    implementation("io.prometheus:simpleclient_pushgateway:0.16.0")
```

My application.yml looks like below

```
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
        pushgateway:
          enabled: true
          base-url: http://0.0.0.0:9091
          job: main-job
          push-rate: 5s
        descriptions: true
```

But when I navigate to `/metrics` endpoint, the metrics are having values as 0.

example :

```
spring_batch_step_seconds_max{instance="",job="job",job_name="job-job-flow",name="process-5.csv",status="FAILED"} 0
spring_batch_step_seconds_max{instance="",job="job",job_name="job-job-flow",name="process-6.csv",status="COMPLETED"} 0
spring_batch_step_seconds_max{instance="",job="job",job_name="job-job-flow",name="process-7.csv",status="FAILED"} 0
spring_batch_step_seconds_max{instance="",job="job",job_name="job-job-flow",name="process-2csv",status="FAILED"} 0
spring_batch_step_seconds_max{instance="",job="job",job_name="job-job-flow",name="start-job-job",status="COMPLETED"} 0
```

I've checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207793/why-does-micrometer-timer-returns-zero), which indicates that we need to configure a registry but if I'm using the auto configured `PrometheusPushGatewayManager` by adding the `simpleclient_pushgateway` dependency, how to configure a registry ?

Keeping a breakpoint and viewing the value of `Metrics.globalRegistry.meters[1]` shows values like `SampleImpl{duration(seconds)=392.074203242, duration(nanos)=3.92074203242E11, startTimeNanos=1098399187818886}`. So they are captured but not pushed properly.

Am I missing something to configure for getting the metrics pushed properly to the gateway ?

Comment: `I have the below dependencies added in my build.gradle which means PrometheusPushGatewayManager bean is auto-configured and needs to push metrics to the gateway configured.`: how did you come to that conclusion? Is that documented somewhere like that? Spring Batch pushes metrics to micrometer's global registry, which is an empty composite by default. You need to make sure that you have at least one registry added in that composite before your job is started.

Comment: @FadhelMahmoudBenHassine I'm stuck on how exactly need to do that ? Can you share me some example ?

Comment: I've checked this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207793/why-does-micrometer-timer-returns-zero), which indicates that we need to configure a registry but if I'm using the auto configured PrometheusPushGatewayManager by adding the simpleclient_pushgateway dependency, how to configure a registry ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a sample for an auto-configuration with Boot. Try to check Boot's documenation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.export.prometheus

Comment: Yeah I have come across this already and have implemented as per the documentation but the metrics aren't getting pushed to the gateway